# 3D Cursor as Transform Pivot Point is not the center of rotation? Old project version fine

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to rotate around the 3D cursor but it seems to no longer be the pivot point, however it does affect where the pivot point is. I opened an earlier version of my project and it works just fine. I believe I hit a button or key combo that changed a setting I'm not aware of. I have confirmed rotating things in Object mode has the same odd behavior as Edit.

Using Blender 3.4.1

Here you can see a selection of points (orange) have been rotated more than 360 degrees in order to see where the actual pivot point is (center of that round-ish set of points).
[image: pivot point affected by but not at 3d cursor]

Here we can see the 3D cursor at a new location and the pivot point affected (however still not the actual point for pivoting).
[image: pivot point moves with 3d cursor]

Double-checking the pivot point setting is 3D Cursor:
[image: pivot point set to 3d cursor]

Comment: Actually I cannot really see what is going on there. And I'm wondering how much of an effect the activated _Proportional Editing_ has in this case. In general I can only say, in my version 3.4.1 the 3D cursor as pivot point works so maybe we need your file to check it out.

Comment: Proportional Editing does not affect the issue at hand if on or not but it does make the issue easier to see. Points not selected but which fall in the proportional area will be transformed in a graded scale. Some of the points will be strongly affected, others weakly: it depends on the distance from  the other selected points. The project is done now. I'm not looking to share files but hear from someone who grocks blender and can say "that's a bug" or "you hit a button"

Comment: I'm not sure why you are explaining to me how Proportional Editing works, I know this quite well. What I meant is I cannot see anything in the screenshot, just a bunch of points which make it hard to see what kind of transformation you did to them and if this was in any way not working as expected, off the 3D cursor and to what extent proportional editing had any part in this transformation. And from my own experience I can only repeat the cursor as pivot point generally works in 3.4.1, since I use quite often. So if it is one, it's not a very common bug I suppose.